# Power BI - basic column refferencing

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, analytics

I am somehow unable to figure out column refferencing in an IF statement Power Query M.

I want to replace value in a column based on a condition evaluating string comparison on different column.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Previous step",
    {"Col_1", each if [Col_2] = "ghi" then null else _}
)
```

"Col_1" - contains floating numbers
Col_2 - contains 4x text value

===============================================================
In this example i want to replace the value if string in Col_2 equal to "ghi"

```
Data:
Col_1 | Col_2
0     | abc
12    | def
100   | ghi

Expected result:
Col_1 | Col_2
0     | abc
12    | def
null  | ghi
```

===============================================================
Please advise ...

I tried differently by trying, googling, even chatGPT 3.5 ... with a damn column refferencing.

Comment: Paste your sample data and expected output and please mark your old questions as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in powerquery. You need to do a replace

```
let Source =#table({"Column1", "Column2"},{{0,"abc"},{12,"def"},{300,"ghi"}}),
Update =Table.ReplaceValue(Source, each [Column1], each if [Column2] ="ghi" then null else [Column1] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
in Update
```

[image]

Comment: I did thanks a lot.

So column refferencing was fine, formula was not.

Comment: I edited the post a bit when I added the example, so the column names are different. Solution works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

`Table.TransformColumns` cannot cross-reference other columns. Instead you can use `Table.ReplaceValue` like:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(
    #"Previous step",
    each [Col_1],
    each if [Col_2] = "ghi" then null else [Col_1],
    Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"Col_1"} )
```